# Postgres Find % value of field against different row in result set

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that contains a numeric value for the # of times an action has happened, an a key to describe that action and the time that action occurred.

```
Table: action
Id | Data | Key | timestamp 
1 | 10 | 'accepted' | '2022-01-16 19:00:00.000 -0500'
1 | 5  | 'rejected' | '2022-01-16 19:00:00.000 -0500'
1 | 22 | 'accepted' | '2022-01-17 19:00:00.000 -0500'
1 | 3  | 'rejected' | '2022-01-17 19:00:00.000 -0500'
```

I'd like to query against that an find the % of a particular action (in this case we'll say accepted), against the rejected actions on the same timestamp.

So in the above case I'd ideally like to take get a result of

```
accepted | 2022-01-16 | 66% (10 / 15)
accepted | 2022-01-17 | 88% (22 / 25)
```

How would I construct the query to do the division on 1 row against the total from multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation for the total of the rejected.
And divide that by the total of both.

```
SELECT
  MIN(Key) AS Key
, CAST(a.timestamp AS DATE) AS "Date" 
, CONCAT(100*SUM(CASE WHEN a.Key = 'rejected' THEN a.Data ELSE 0 END) / NULLIF(SUM(a.Data),0), '%') AS PercentageRejected
FROM action a
WHERE a.Id = 1
GROUP BY Id, CAST(a.timestamp AS DATE) 
ORDER BY Id, CAST(a.timestamp AS DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  id,
        key, 
        date(t_timestamp), 
        concat((data*100/sum(data) over w),'%') as accept_rate
from action
WINDOW w as 
    (partition by t_timestamp, id order by id)
order by id asc, date asc;
```

---

windows function manual link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html.
concat string fucntion link:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

You may want to change column name `timestamp` to something else, since
SQL-standard all set timestamp as reserved, even though it's not reserved in PostgreSQL.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html